# What happens to while loop when it starts finding an element from array and the element is not found?

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop, iteration

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int i = 0;
while(arr[i]<=6){
  i++;
}
```

**What happens to the while loop if the element is not found in the array.**

As in the above example, What will happen to i as 6 is not found in the array should it incresed till infinity or it will stop at the end of array length.

I got the output but I have some confusion in the while loop where i is incremented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void arrayTrasversal(int *arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
int partition(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[low];
    int i = low + 1;
    int j = high;
    do{
        while (arr[i] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if(i<j){
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
    }while (i < j);
    swap(&arr[low],&arr[j]);
    return j;

}
void quickSort(int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    int partitionIndex;
    if (low < high)
    {
        partitionIndex = partition(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, partitionIndex - 1);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex + 1, high);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 3, 9, 1, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    arrayTrasversal(arr, n); // Before sorting
    quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    arrayTrasversal(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
What happens to i in this case if it increases till last indent and not found element greater than pivot

while (arr[i] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
```

Should I use another condition like this

```
while (arr[i] <= pivot && i<=high)
        {
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour when `i` reaches `5` because the index overruns the array.

Comment: It will keep increasing. As soon as it gets greater than 5 the code will cause a buffer overflow and the result is Undefined Behaviour. It is your job as the coder to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Bad question. You can run it yourself on the IDE and read the error.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen it is undefined what will happen.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen Note that when code exhibits undefined behaviour (as in this case) simply building it and forming an opinion based on the 'observed' behaviour will *not* prove useful.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen ThankYou for your response. I've tried it on IDE. But I've some confusion in other program where this while loop is used.

Answer (score 0):

When `i==5` and code attempts `arr[i]` the result is *undefined behavior* (UB) as code attempts to read beyond that array `arr[]`.

> ... should it incresed till infinity or it will stop at the end of array length.

No - there is no *should*.  It is *undefined behavior* (UB).

Comment: It means it will come out of loop after iterating the whole array? ThankYou

Comment: Basically, it will not come out of the loop; The loop will keep on iterating upwards until it causes buffer overflow and crashes the program.

Comment: @MohammadQasim "It means it will come out of loop after iterating the whole array" --> Maybe, maybe not.  It is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

Interresting

You will enter in an overflow of the buffer `arr` because When `i` reaches the value `5`, the pointer `*(arr+i)` will start to read **after** the data initially allocated to your buffer (`arr`), so this can lead to many behaviors

In other terms, this is called an undefined behavior caused by a buffer overflow.

It wont stop a the end of the array and try to increase till infinity, however I'm pretty sure that you will go into a segfault error because it tried to read outside the data segment.